Using the Superset API how do I export a dashboard and a chart in PDF (or PNG or JPEG) format from the REST API?
Is it possible to export rendered Dashboards and Charts as pdf from the API? I see no way to export a Dashboard as pdf and found this old discussion. Has anything changed for Dashboards?
For charts, pdf is not an accepted result_format in the payload when fetching chart data from api/v1/chart/data. Is there a way to extend Superset to allow for Chart pdfs?
If not pdf then is it possible down download the image of either?
